# jQuery.dialog() is not doing anything

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got a simple list of thumbnails that link to a larger version of that image, which I want to display in a jQuery modal dialog window:

```
$('a.modal').bind('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var outputHolder = $('<div id="modal-output"></div>');
    $("body").append(outputHolder);
    outputHolder.html('<img src="'+$this.attr("href")+'">', null, function() {
        outputHolder.dialog();
    });
    return false;
});
```

The outputHolder div is being added to the page correctly, and it's being populated by the image, which is great... however, the `.dialog()` command is not doing anything, it isn't adding the dialog tags and the HTML just looks like this:

```
<div id="uimodal-output">
     <img src="image.jpg">
</div>
```

I am using the following files:

- jquery-1.10.2.js (v1.10.2 - comes with ASP.NET MVC5 by default)
- jquery-ui.min.js (v1.11.0 - latest version)
- bootstrap.js (v3.0.0 - comes with ASP.NET MVC5 by default)

Any suggestions on how to fix this please? I'm not getting any errors at all in Chrome's console.

Thank you

Comment: An `id` starting with a `.` can't be valid? can it? That would be so confusing for humans let alone jQuery selectors e.g. `$('#.modal-output')`

Comment: Followup: Apparently HTML 5 (only) allows these type of names in id values, but I strongly recommend you stick to HTML 4 rules for compatibility (if you care about IE 8, 9 etc). :)

Comment: Sorry, I copied some code and butchered it :> Will update now. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it like

```
$('a.modal').bind('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var outputHolder = $("<div id='.modal-output'></div>");
    $("body").append(outputHolder);
    outputHolder.html('<img src="'+$this.attr("href")+'">').dialog();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working now, though my styles are a little out since the jQuery UI dialog isn't compatible with bootstrap - will need to play around a bit.